# What does "to his feet" mean?

Tags: prepositions

Harry scrambled to his feet. What does the preposition "to" mean in "to his feet"?

Comment: The "to" is equivalent here to "onto"; that is, Harry was presumably either lying down or sitting down before "scrambling [on]to his feet" (i.e., standing up).

Answer (score 1):

> **Get to/on one's feet (idiom):** Get to a standing position
>
> [Source: Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-ones-feet)

The "to" is simply **a part of the phrase**; it indicates that the person is getting "to" something, like **up to** their feet.